# meteor settings in webstorm IDE

Tags: meteor, webstorm

Anyone has problem setting up meteor Environments Variable in Webstorm 10?

[image]

When I do Meteor.settings, it returns {}, I can do Meteor --settings=settings.json in Terminal, however since IDE provide such feature why not just use it?

Answer (score 1):

You just write '--settings settings.json' in the program arguments box like below. It can be same like doing meteor --settings settings.json in terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

as you can see from https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2005, `METEOR_SETTINGS` environment variable can only be used for the bundled application, but can't be applied to `meteor run`. So you can't use it when running application in WebStorm